# How to sign an Applet with a trusted certificate?

Tags: java, security, ant, applet, certificate

I'm working on an application that runs some applets with self-signed certificates, but java 8 blocks applets with self-signed certificates... and now users who updated their Java version can't use the applets, a big trouble!

My company bought a trusted certificate, and now I'm trying to sign the applets with this certificate.

The old signature is this in build.xml: (it signs when I run Ant to create the .EAR)

```
<signjar keystore="${web.etc}/company.ks" storepass="pass" alias="aliasname" lazy="yes" maxmemory="256m">
            <fileset dir="${docroot}/applets/appletName/" includes="${appletName.name}" />
</signjar>
```

I received a new key with `.jks` extension
but I can't just put the new key on the old's folder and change the `keystore` and `storepass`, it doesn't work... build fails.

Has anyone already done something similar?

Need I write something in the manifest of the jars?

Comment: [Signing Applets Using RSA Certificates](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/certificates.html#JSDPG886)

Comment: Wouldnt that be company.jks instead of company.ks? In any way, you should post the build errors.